# Jquery Ajax Post On AWS Instance Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, amazon-web-services

I've ran into an incredibly weird problem that I'm not entirely sure how to debug. I wrote a POST function here that works perfectly fine locally and then breaks when deployed to AWS.

```
$.ajax({
    url: upload_url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {'blobs': JSON.stringify(Blobs)},
    success: function(data) {}
});
```

Any ideas as to why post requests are not being called? I've console.log'd inside the AJAX call, and I see the log locally... but not on AWS. The code is identical.

Comment: Likely to be unrelated to the web host itself, unless you're going across domains. Are you sure that jQuery is loaded correctly?

Comment: Yeah its loaded correctly... Its rather odd.

Comment: can you add error handler and log the results?

`$.ajax({
        url: upload_url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: {'blobs': JSON.stringify(Blobs)},
        success: function(data) {},
        error: function(e){console.log(e);}
});`